# Implementing a cache using SoftReference

Tags: java

I have a program that visualizes data sets. Several data sets can be loaded at a time (but only one data set can be displayed at a time), and the data sets can be large enough that memory becomes an issue. What I was thinking to do is to implement a caching mechanism so that the data sets are each cached in their own temporary file, and the GUI holds a soft reference to each data set so that memory is used more efficiently. This is what I approximately had in mind:

```
class DataSetReference extends SoftReference<DataSet> {
   private File cache;

   public DataSetReference(DataSet referent, byte[] rawData) {
      super(referent);
      // Skip error checking, etc.
      cache = File.createTempFile("abc", null);
      writeDataToCache(cache, rawData);
   }

   @Override
   public DataSet get() {
      if (super.get() == null) {
         refreshReferenceFromCache();
      }
      return super.get();
   }

   private refreshReferenceFromCache() {
      DataSet ds = parseDataSetFromFile(cache);
      // profit???
   }
}
```

but then I realized that `SoftReference` is **immutable**, which kills that idea. It seems like what I have to do is to recreate the `DataSet` instance outside of the soft reference, then create a new soft reference and replace the old reference with the new in the GUI components that visualize the data sets.

My question is: are there some patterns or examples for implementing caches with `SoftReference`? This is the first time I've attempted to use soft references, and I would feel more comfortable after looking at some other implementations. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to create a new SoftReference to refer to a new object. If you use a field of type `SoftReference<DataSet>` *instead of extending it*, you can do that easily.

Comment: `SoftReference` is usually just a wrapper to the actual object reference, and all these references are managed by the container. I would turn the problem around and build a `Container<DataSet>` that manages the  `SoftReference` of `DataSet` and encapsulate the serialisation behaviour.

Comment: check how [guava cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) is implemented

Comment: @immibis Thanks, I refactored the class as you suggested.

Comment: @harshtuna I looked into guava cache and the cache loading mechanism looks  interesting. Thanks for the link.